# mb_eregi_replace multiple matches get them

Tags: php, pattern-matching

```
$string = 'test check one two test3';
$result = mb_eregi_replace ( 'test|test2|test3' , '<$1>' ,$string ,'i');
echo $result;
```

This should deliver: `<test> check one two <test3>`

Is it possible to get, that **test** and **test3** was found, without using another match function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
$string = 'test check one two test3';
$matches = array();
$result = preg_replace_callback('/test|test2|test3/i' , function($match) use ($matches) {
    $matches[] = $match;
    return '<'.$match[0].'>';
}, $string);
echo $result;
```

Here `preg_replace_callback` will call the passed callback function for each match of the pattern (note that [its syntax differs from POSIX](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix)). In this case the callback function is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) that adds the match to the `$matches` array and returns the substitution string that the matches are to be replaced by.

Another approach would be to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) to split the string at the matched delimiters while also capturing the delimiters:

```
$parts = preg_split('/test|test2|test3/i', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The result is an array of alternating non-matching and matching parts.

Comment: Don't forget the `u` flag (UTF-8). The original choice of `mb_...` suggests there might be some sort of multi-byte encoding involved (let's hope it *is* UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, eregi is deprecated.
You could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $str = 'test check one two test3';
    $to_match = array("test", "test2", "test3");

    $rep = array();
    foreach($to_match as $val){
        $rep[$val] = "<$val>";
    }
    echo strtr($str, $rep);
?>
```

This too allows you to easily add more strings to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Hi following function used to found the any word from string

```
<?php
function searchword($string, $words)
 {
    $matchFound = count($words);// use tha no of word you want to search
    $tempMatch = 0;
    foreach ( $words as $word )
    {
        preg_match('/'.$word.'/',$string,$matches);
        //print_r($matches);
        if(!empty($matches))
        {
            $tempMatch++;
        }   
    }
    if($tempMatch==$matchFound)
    {
        return "found";
    }
    else
    {
        return "notFound";
    }
}

$string = "test check one two test3";
/*** an array of words to highlight ***/
$words = array('test', 'test3');

$string =  searchword($string, $words);
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is utf-8, you could use preg_replace instead

```
$string = 'test check one two test3';
$result = preg_replace('/(test3)|(test2)|(test)/ui' , '<$1>' ,$string);
echo $result;
```

Oviously with this kind of data to match the result will be suboptimal

```
<test> check one two <test>3
```

You'll need a longer approach than a direct search and replace with regular expressions (surely if your patterns are prefixes of other patterns)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, the code you want to enhance does not seem to comply with its initial purpose (not at least in my computer). You can try something like this:

```
$string = 'test check one two test3';
$result = mb_eregi_replace('(test|test2|test3)', '<\1>', $string);
echo $result;
```

I've removed the `i` flag (which of course makes little sense here). Still, you'd still need to make the expression greedy.

As for the original question, here's a little proof of concept:

```
function replace($match){
    $GLOBALS['matches'][] = $match;
    return "<$match>";
}

$string = 'test check one two test3';
$matches = array();
$result = mb_eregi_replace('(test|test2|test3)', 'replace(\'\1\')', $string, 'e');
var_dump($result, $matches);
```

Please note this code is horrible and potentially insecure. I'd honestly go with the  `preg_replace_callback()` solution proposed by Gumbo.